# "PHP Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations", when initializing a static inline?

Tags: php, compiler-errors, php-7

I am wondering why is it that my static variable initialization does not work with the following declaration:

```
function validate()
{
    static $timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(); // Error here

    ...
}
```

The line with `static ...` generates the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations

If I do the following, though, it works as expected:

```
function validate()
{
    static $timezones = null;
    if(!isset($timezones))
    {
        $timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
    }
    ...
}
```

So I have a way around the problem, but I am wondering why is it that the first method fails?

Comment: Please stop tag spamming. Your post cannot possibly be C++ and PHP simultaneously, and that is absolutely NOT C++ code you posted. You're not new here; you know how tags work. Stop randomly adding them.

Comment: Why it fails explained in the error message.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah... Sorry, it was a suggested tag and since I do a lot of C++ too... Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on php documentation; You cannot initialize static variable with another non constant expression or variable.

Which means if you want to assign a value to static variable this value should be a an integer, string etc.

What you did here is against static word rule in PHP you are assigning a dynamic value to **$timezones** variable

```
static $timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(); // Error here
```

Check for detailed information.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: Ah, you gave us the wrong link, the correct link is this one: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static since my sample shows a static variable in a function, not in an object. And a constant is not required. You can have an expression, but no function calls.

Comment: I am changing my answer.